# "which sentence(s) is" vs. "which sentence(s) are": how should one conjugate a verb when the subject is a word followed by (s)?

Tags: singular-vs-plural, subject-verb-agreement

I wonder how to conjugate a verb when the subject is a word followed by `(s)`. For example, which of the following two sentence(s) is/are correct:

1. Which program(s) are needed?
2. Which program(s) is needed?

?

Comment: This is a basic question that can be answered by reference to any book or website on english grammar. Just look up (or google) "english agreement between subject and verb"

Comment: @PeterJennings The subject is "program(s)". Is it plural or singular?

Comment: Ah sorry , I too misunderstood your question . I think the corrected answer below covers it.

Comment: This problem can't be unique to English, it would seem to affect any language that has agreement between words.   How would you solve it in your language(s)

Comment: @JamesK I've used English >99.9% of the time over the past 10 years. I don't recall how my native language handles that case.

Comment: This question may be better on [English.se] since it is more a matter of how English is used rather than learning a feature of English.  I hope you see the distinction.  Indeed it is perhaps more interesting on [French.se] since French is a much more inflected language, and there can be complex chains of dependent forms of words:  "Il/elle est un(e) bon(ne) acteur/actrice"  and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Which program is needed?*

*Which programs are needed?*

*Which program(s) is/are needed?*

When the subject is plural, the verb must also agree in plural form.  If the subject's number is ambiguous, the verb must also be ambiguous to accommodate it.  The "is/are" form has become quite common; however, if one wishes to be more formal, then list "program" and "programs" separately, and whichever comes last, match the verb to that.

For example:

*Which program or programs are needed?*  (my preference)

*Which programs or program is needed?*

Comment: Thanks. The subject is "program(s)". Is it plural?

Comment: Ah.  I was not understanding your use of the parenthesized 's'.  If you want the subject to go either way, you need the verb to accommodate it, i.e. _"Which program(s) is/are needed?"_

Comment: I have updated the answer, as I now understand the question better.